# Total disconnectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $T$ be the standard Euclidean topology on $ \mathbb{R}$ and let $\mathbb{R}\cup{a}$ with $A\notin \mathbb{R}$ have the topogy with basis $B=\{U|U\in T\}\cup\{(V\backslash \{0\})\cup\{a\}|V\text{ is an open neighbourhood of }0\}$.
Let $X=\{0,a\}\cup\{1/n|n\geq 1\}$.

> 1 How do I show that $X$ is totally disconnected?

**My idea**:
1 I thought that it would be best to show that every subset of $X$ with more than one element is not connected. There are four/three types: those without $0,a$; without $a$ but with $0$ (or vice versa which is similar); and with both $0$ and $a$.

I know that singletons of the form ${1/n}$ are open in $X$. So subsets with more than one of these can easily be partitioned in two open disjoint sets.

But what if I have the set $\{0,1/2\}$? This cannot be partitioned, since $\{0\}$ is not open in $X$. Would that not mean that it is connected?

Comment: To show {0, 1/2} is not connected you only need {0} to be open in {0, 1/2}, not necessarily in X.

Comment: ...and, more relevantly,  the same applies to {0, a}.

Comment: This is false. All open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ are still connected, e.g.

Comment: The claim is that X is td, not $\mathbb{R}$. (X being $\{0,a\}\cup\{1/n|n\geq 1\}$, not $\mathbb{R}\cup{a}$.)